# JavaScript adding classes on multiple modals

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm kind of desperate. I'm trying to make the same modal as Behance has when you click on one of the little windows but I can't get my JavaScript to work. I'm not able to show "test2".

```js
function modalActive(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("window")[0].classList.add("modalActive")
};

function closeModal(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("window")[0].classList.remove("modalActive")
};
```

```css
.gallery-item {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.window {
  display: none;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  Background-color: gray;
  z-index: 100000;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.modalActive {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-item">
  <button class="button" onclick="modalActive()">derp</button>
</div>
<div class="window">
  <button class="close" onclick="closeModal()">×</button>
  test1
</div>


<div class="gallery-item">
   <button class="button" onclick="modalActive()">derp</button>
</div>
<div class="window">
  <button class="close">×</button>
  test2 - im not able to see this due to some error in my code/knowledge
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to target a specific modal to open when clicking on the buttons. At the moment you are only ever finding the first modal and setting the `modalActive` class.

I have updated your code below to pass the modal id number when clicking on a button.

```js
function modalActive(id){
  document.getElementsByClassName("window-" + id)[0].classList.add("modalActive")
};

function closeModal(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("modalActive")[0].classList.remove("modalActive")
};
```

```css
.gallery-item {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.window {
  display: none;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  Background-color: gray;
  z-index: 100000;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.modalActive {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-item">
  <button class="button" onclick="modalActive(1)">derp</button>
</div>
<div class="window window-1">
  <button class="close" onclick="closeModal()">×</button>
  test1
</div>


<div class="gallery-item">
   <button class="button" onclick="modalActive(2)">derp</button>
</div>
<div class="window window-2">
  <button class="close" onclick="closeModal()">×</button>
  test2 - im not able to see this due to some error in my code/knowledge
</div>
```